# Excel Formula Count Issue

Tags: excel

**Background Summary**
I have a really simple excel file with 2 sheets:

**Sheet #1 (Date)** = A single column of time and date stamps.
**Sheet #2 (Rep)** = A report table broken down by day of the month and hour(12 AM -11:59 PM) .

Basically on Sheet #2, It counts the number of date/time occurrences that fall between the referenced hour. For example, for the 12:00 AM hour, it counts all occurrences that fall between 12:00 AM - 12:59 AM. For the next hour, it will count all occurences that fall between 1:00 AM - 1:59 AM and so on. Please see the attached excel spreadsheet. In short, the table allows me to see the total number of occurences hourly and for the entire month

**The ISSUE**
The issue I'm having is that there is a total of 208,784 date instances. However, when I calculate the total number of instances for the given month it only counts 208,171. I cannot figure out why 613 instances are not being counted. Please see details below

**My Forumuala used to count each hour (5:00 AM hour example below)**
=COUNTIFS(Date!A1:A208790, ">=" & "11/5/2015 5:00 AM",Date!A1:A208790, "<=" & "11/5/2015 5:59 AM")

**Excel File Download**
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8m6eCe12n37MTJ2MTY2WGZCakU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Perhaps those missing instances are not a correct date/time format?  btw:  your sheet is not found at that link.

Comment: To add what @durbnpoisn just said format the date/time column as "general".  Then scroll through the column.  if it is a true Date/time you should see a number in decimal format.  If it not you will see text.

Comment: I apologize. I have updated the link in the original post - https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8m6eCe12n37MTJ2MTY2WGZCakU/view?usp=sharing . @ScottCraner, I do see the decimal number when I convert it to "general".

Answer (score 0):

The 613 are falling in the space between 12:59 and 1:00.  You will find that this is a floating decimal issue.

Even though you see no seconds, way down in the decimal where it would not effect the time, are numbers that make it larger than 59 minutes but less than the hour.

Change your formula to this:

```
=COUNTIFS(Date!A1:A208790, ">=" & "11/5/2015 5:00 AM",Date!A1:A208790, "<" & "11/5/2015 6:00 AM")
```

By getting everything less than the full hour and greater than or equal to the previous full hour you should not lose any.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. I was leaving the seconds value out in the formula. In other words my time references in the formula SHOULD HAVE looked like this:

Start = 5:00:00 AM 
End = 5:59:59 AM

Referencing the seconds value within the formula was the missing piece here. Thanks guys!

Comment: yup did you see my answer from ten minutes ago?

Comment: I'm sorry, I missed it.